# JAVA API to create a keystore and attaching a csr and keypair to it

Tags: java, security, bouncycastle, keytool, csr

I need to attach an existing csr and keypair to a keystore. Given below is an implementation that uses GUI(java swing) to take the input from the user such as keystore name, alias,common name, organization etc.

I try to link the csr to the keystore using keystore.setkeyentry(...), however the keystore is still empty.

I have attached my code below, any help will be very useful:

This code below is used to create a csr

```
            public String getCSR(String cn, String ou, String o, String l,String s) throws Exception {
            byte[] csr = generatePKCS10(cn, ou, o, l,s,"US");

            return new String(csr);
        }


private static byte[] generatePKCS10(String CN, String OU, String O,
                String L, String S, String C) throws Exception {
            // generate PKCS10 certificate request
            String sigAlg = "MD5WithRSA";
            PKCS10 pkcs10 = new PKCS10(publicKey);
            Signature signature = Signature.getInstance(sigAlg);
            signature.initSign(privateKey);
            // common, orgUnit, org, locality, state, country
            X500Principal principal = new X500Principal( "CN=Ole Nordmann, OU=ACME, O=Sales, C=NO");

       //     pkcs10CertificationRequest kpGen = new PKCS10CertificationRequest(sigAlg, principal, publicKey, null, privateKey);  
         //   byte[] c = kpGen.getEncoded();  
            X500Name x500name=null;
            x500name= new X500Name(principal.getEncoded());
          pkcs10.encodeAndSign(x500name, signature);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(bs);
            pkcs10.print(ps);
            byte[] c = bs.toByteArray();
            try {
                if (ps != null)
                    ps.close();
                if (bs != null)
                    bs.close();
            } catch (Throwable th) {
            }
            return c;
        }


        public static X509Certificate generateX509Certificate(String certEntry) throws IOException {

            InputStream in = null;
            X509Certificate cert = null;
            try {
                byte[] certEntryBytes = certEntry.getBytes();
                in = new ByteArrayInputStream(certEntryBytes);
                CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

                cert = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(in);
            } catch (CertificateException ex) {

            } finally {
                if (in != null) {
                        in.close();
                }
            }
            return cert;
        }
```

In the main method I do the following to create a keystore and attach it to the csr

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());


                        char[] pass = password.toCharArray();
                        ks.load(null, pass);

                        ks.store(fos, pass);
                        fos.close();
                         GenerateCSR gcsr = GenerateCSR.getInstance();

                    System.out.println("Public Key:\n"+gcsr.getPublicKey().toString());

                    System.out.println("Private Key:\n"+gcsr.getPrivateKey().toString());

                    String csr = gcsr.getCSR(CN,OU,O,L,S);

                    System.out.println("CSR Request Generated!!");
                    System.out.println(csr);


                    X509Certificate[] certChain = new X509Certificate[1];
                 //   certChain[0]= gcsr.generateX509Certificate(csr);
                    X509Certificate myCert = (X509Certificate) CertificateFactory
                                                 .getInstance("X509")
                                                 .generateCertificate(
                                                    // string encoded with default charset
                                                    new ByteArrayInputStream(csr.getBytes())
                                                 ); 
                    certChain[0]= myCert;
                    ks.setKeyEntry("alias", (Key)gcsr.getPrivateKey(), pass, certChain);
```

When I check the contents of the keystore, it is empty.
Any advice will be appreciated

Thank You!!!

Comment: You could probably remove all the import statements from the samples, and remove the GUI pairr entirely, only leaving a sample that generates a keyPair and CSR and that demonstrates how using '.setKeyEntry()' fails to add the key to the store. (That would make answering the question a bit easier :))

Comment: Great advice!! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have **two main mistakes**:

- a Certificate Signing Request aka **CSR aka PKCS10 is NOT a certificate**. `CertificateFactory.generateCertificate` will only read a certificate and not a CSR, and when you provide it with a CSR it throws an exception which your code cleverly suppresses with no indication to anybody there was a serious problem. The commented-out code you had in your earlier revision was closer to that needed to generate a certificate.
- (if you do create/have a valid certificate) `KeyStore.set*` only sets the entry in the in-memory KeyStore object. If you want the keystore contents saved somewhere like in a file after your program exits, you **must `store` it AFTER doing the 'set'(s)**.

Here is your code modified enough it works as I believe you want. Except for trivial formatting and scaffolding, spots I changed are marked by `//--` for deletions and `//**` for additions. Even so I do not recommend it because:

- I continue your use of the unsupported `sun.security` classes, even though you are using BC and it has supported classes for PKCS10 and related bits, plus a CSR is only needed if you want to request a certificate from a CA; to generate a cert yourself just generating the cert directly is easier
- (less serious) in recent versions of BC pkix has been split to a separate jar and `X509V3CertificateGenerator` is now deprecated in favor of `X509v3CertificateBuilder`

---

```
//nopackage
import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.cert.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.security.auth.x500.*;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.X509Principal;
import org.bouncycastle.x509.X509V3CertificateGenerator;

//--import sun.security.pkcs.PKCS10; -- Java7
import sun.security.pkcs10.PKCS10; //** Java8
import sun.security.x509.X500Name;

public class SO40350607GenerateCertIntoKeystoreFile8 {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
        //**dummy value for test
        KeyPairGenerator kpgen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA"); 
        kpgen.initialize(1024); keyPair = kpgen.generateKeyPair();

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        char[] pass = "password".toCharArray();
        ks.load(null, pass);
        //--ks.store(fos, pass);    useless here
        //--fos.close();

        String csr = new String(generatePKCS10("CommonName","OrgUnit","Org","Locality","State", "US"));
        System.out.println("CSR Request Generated!!");
        System.out.println(csr);

        //--X509Certificate myCert = (X509Certificate) CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509")
        //--    .generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(csr.getBytes()) ); // string encoded with default charset*/
        X509Certificate myCert = generateCertificate2 (csr); //**
        X509Certificate[] certChain = new X509Certificate[]{myCert};
        ks.setKeyEntry("alias", keyPair.getPrivate(), pass, certChain);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream ("newksfile");
        ks.store(fos,pass); fos.close(); //** NOW store to file
    }
    private static KeyPair keyPair;

    private static byte[] generatePKCS10(String CN, String OU, String O,
            String L, String S, String C) throws Exception {
        // generate PKCS10 certificate request
        String sigAlg = "SHA1WithRSA"; //** don't use "MD5WithRSA" even for CSR 
        PKCS10 pkcs10 = new PKCS10(keyPair.getPublic());
        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance(sigAlg);
        signature.initSign(keyPair.getPrivate());
        // common, orgUnit, org, locality, state, country
        //--X500Principal principal = new X500Principal( "CN=Ole Nordmann, OU=ACME, O=Sales, C=NO");
        //--X500Name x500name= new X500Name(principal.getEncoded());
        //** can do this directly (and better)
        X500Name x500name = new X500Name ("CN="+CN+",OU="+OU+",O="+O+",L="+L+",S="+S+",C="+C);
        pkcs10.encodeAndSign(x500name, signature);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(bs);
        pkcs10.print(ps);
        byte[] c = bs.toByteArray();
        ps.close(); //** bs,ps are never null, ps.close automatically closes underlying bs,
        //** and anyway BAOS doesn't need to be closed (although most streams do)
        return c;
    }

    //** (whole) routine to generate an actual (though selfsigned) certificate 
    public static X509Certificate generateCertificate2 (String csrpem) throws Exception {  
        String csrtrim = csrpem.replaceAll("-----[^\\n]*\\n","").replaceAll("\\r?\\n","");
        //--PKCS10 pkcs10 = new PKCS10 (Base64.decode (csrtrim.toCharArray())); --Java7
        PKCS10 pkcs10 = new PKCS10 (Base64.getDecoder().decode (csrtrim.getBytes())); //Java8
        // or use the one we had before encoding it -- or the input data directly?? 

        // X509V3CertificateGenerator is deprecated but stay with it for now
        X509V3CertificateGenerator cert = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();   
        cert.setSerialNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(1));   //or generate a random number  
        cert.setSubjectDN(pkcs10.getSubjectName().asX500Principal());  
        cert.setIssuerDN(pkcs10.getSubjectName().asX500Principal()); //same since it is self-signed  
        cert.setPublicKey(pkcs10.getSubjectPublicKeyInfo());  
        Date now = new Date(); cert.setNotBefore(now);  
        now.setYear(now.getYear()+1); cert.setNotAfter(now);  
        cert.setSignatureAlgorithm("SHA1WithRSA");   
        PrivateKey signingKey = keyPair.getPrivate();    
        return cert.generate(signingKey, "BC");  
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have another question - import sun.security.pkcs.PKCS10; does not seem to work. Therefore PKCS10 pkcs10 = new PKCS10 (Base64.decode (csrtrim.toCharArray())); gives an error. Any work around for this problem?

Comment: @user6784240: Oops! The IDE where I did this is still on Java7 and on checking 8 I see it moved this class to `sun.security.pkcs10` -- and also changed `java.util.Base64` which I had forgotten wasn't official in 7. Thus confirming my advice about unsupported classes twice! See edit for a minimal fix. But my real _recommendation_ is the comment: you don't need a CSR here at all, instead generate the cert directly from the data that would have been in the CSR.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This works. The reason I need a CSR is because I need to get it signed from a CA.

Comment: @user6784240: Your Q didn't say that. You might consider how `keytool` handles this: `-genkeypair` generates a keypair and selfsigned cert (for that key) and puts them (together) in a keystore; `-certreq` uses keypair and name _from_ keystore to create CSR output to screen or file (not keystore); when you get a cert (and usually chain also) back from a CA, `-importcert` _replaces_ the selfsigned cert in the keystore entry with the 'proper' cert chain. ...

Comment: ... If you (can) have BC, try the documented (and apparently stable) `org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder` with probably (I didn't test) the result of `org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder`.